# Working of multiple LinkedList object in a method

Tags: java, linked-list

I was going through a sum on geeksforgeeks.com for adding two linked lists. And I am confused in the answer provided.

```
Node addTwoLists(Node first, Node second) {
        Node res = null; // res is head node of the resultant list
        Node prev = null;
        Node temp = null;
        int carry = 0, sum;

        while (first != null || second != null) //while both lists exist
        {
            // Calculate value of next digit in resultant list.
            // The next digit is sum of following things
            // (i)  Carry
            // (ii) Next digit of first list (if there is a next digit)
            // (ii) Next digit of second list (if there is a next digit)
            sum = carry + (first != null ? first.data : 0)
                    + (second != null ? second.data : 0);

            // update carry for next calulation
            carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0;

            // update sum if it is greater than 10
            sum = sum % 10;

            // Create a new node with sum as data
            temp = new Node(sum);

            // if this is the first node then set it as head of
            // the resultant list
            if (res == null) {
                res = temp;
            } else // If this is not the first node then connect it to the rest.
            {
                prev.next = temp;
            }

            // Set prev for next insertion
            prev = temp;

            // Move first and second pointers to next nodes
            if (first != null) {
                first = first.next;
            }
            if (second != null) {
                second = second.next;
            }
        }

        if (carry > 0) {
            temp.next = new Node(carry);
        }

        // return head of the resultant list
        return res;
    }
```

I understand that we have created three Nodes res, prev and temp and I don't understand how each one of them are getting updated simultaneously.

```
if (res == null) {
                res = temp;
            } else // If this is not the first node then connect it to the rest.
            {
                prev.next = temp;
            }
```

Like here, how the 2nd element would be added in res when we are adding it in prev.next. 
And below :

```
if (carry > 0) {
            temp.next = new Node(carry);
        }
```

If we are adding the last element in temp, how will it reflect in res? 
The code seems to be working but I am having a hard time understanding this concept.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

res, prev and temp are *references* to a Node. When you write something like `res = tmp;` it means that now res and tmp *refer to* the same Node instance, and any changes made to this instance using, for example, res reference will remain when you use tmp reference.

Comment: SInce we have res = temp at one place and later on have prev = temp, so basically all of the three are pointing to the same Node?

Comment: In case when res was null (on first iteration) - yes, sure.

Answer (score 0):

here is the same code but with additional comments to try to help explain what is happening. This code appears to be taking two head nodes from link lists where each node contain a single digit, then adding the digits together to create a new list of single digits (e.g. 1->2->3 and 5->6->7->8 with = 1+5->2+6->3+7->0+8. Note that the third set results in a carry over so the final values in the returned list would be 6->8->0->9).
Thus, this code is not adding to two link lists together, it is adding the data contained
in each of the nodes of the two lists and putting the result into a third list.

My additional comments in the code are prefixed with WCK -

```
Node addTwoLists(Node first, Node second) {
        Node res = null; // res is head node of the resultant list
        Node prev = null;
        Node temp = null;
        int carry = 0, sum;

        while (first != null || second != null) //while both lists exist WCK actually this is While at least one of the lists exists, I believe the comment is wrong and the code is right
        {
            // Calculate value of next digit in resultant list.
            // The next digit is sum of following things
            // (i)  Carry
            // (ii) Next digit of first list (if there is a next digit)
            // (ii) Next digit of second list (if there is a next digit)
            sum = carry + (first != null ? first.data : 0)
                    + (second != null ? second.data : 0);

            // update carry for next calulation
            carry = (sum >= 10) ? 1 : 0; // WCK - assumes sum <20; is only carrying at most 1

            // update sum if it is greater than 10
            sum = sum % 10;

            // Create a new node with sum as data
            temp = new Node(sum); 

            // if this is the first node then set it as head of
            // the resultant list
            // WCK - the first time through the loop, res will be null
            // WCK - each subsequent time through the loop, the else is invoked to link the new node to the one from the previous iteration thus linking them
            if (res == null) {
                res = temp; //WCK - as @ardenit says, both res and temp point to the same node at this point
            } else // If this is not the first node then connect it to the rest.
            {
                prev.next = temp;
            }

            // Set prev for next insertion
            // WCK - now they are starting to set up for the next iteration.
            // WCK - the first time through, res, prev and temp all point to the same node after this statement is executed.
            prev = temp;

            // Move first and second pointers to next nodes
            if (first != null) {
                first = first.next;
            }
            if (second != null) {
                second = second.next;
            }

            // WCK - the first time through the loop, both of the lists passed in
            // have been advanced to the next node in their respective lists.
            // res and prev will point to the temp. As the next iteration of the loop
            // starts, temp will be pointed to a new node while res and prev will 
            // still point to the same node created in the first iteration. As the 
            // second iteration executes, prev is set to point to the new temp 
            // where you see (prev.next = temp) and then prev is advanced to the 
            // this new node as well. res will not be changed again (it is only set
            // once in the first iteration)

        }

        // WCK - now that the loop is finished, there may be a final carry value
        if (carry > 0) {
            temp.next = new Node(carry);
        }

        // return head of the resultant list
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that temp and prev moved to next pointer like you explained and res will not be changed again (Does it mean res is still at the first iteration) but we are return res right and it has all the correct numbers as well? Even though it looks like res is not moving after first iteration but since prev, temp, res points to the same Node, it will have the values updated by prev and temp right?

Comment: prev, temp and res only point to the same node at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: prev, temp and res only point to the same node at the end of the first iteration. In the second iteration, res will continue to point to the first node in the new list (the head node). Temp  will be reassigned (point to ) another node, one that is created in the second iteration ("temp  = new Noded(sum)"). Soon after in this same iteration, prev.next set equal to temp ("prev.next = temp"). This line links the previous node to this new one just created. At this point, prev and res still point to the same node so res.next is the same as prev.next.

Comment: Right after this, you see that prev is then assigned to temp. At that point, res still points to the very first node of the new list, temp and prev point to the second node. As the third iteration executes, temp and prev follow the same pattern as described for the second iteration so that at the end of the third iteration, res still points to the first node, temp and prev will point to the third node. all the nodes stay linked to the next one in the list which means res is the head of the list and the whole list can be accessed by starting with res . Does that help?

Comment: Understood. Since res is at head, if we return it, it will show all the values which is not the case with prev and temp but all of them are a part of the same Node. Correct?

Comment: no. All are not part of the same node. All are part of the same linked list. Res, prev, and temp are only pointing at the same node at the end of the first time through the loop. after the first time thru, res stays unchanged. When completely finished, prev and temp will point to the last node in the list (unless there is a final carry > 0)